# Can we get statistics about the effect of the war in Ukraine on Stack Exchange communities?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Simple questions:

- Is there increased/reduced traffic on communities such as "Russian Language" or the "Russian Stack Overflow"?
- Did you observe (coordinated) efforts of spreading propaganda there, or maybe an increase in harassing comments and such, resulting in more moderation activities?

Comment: There's an increase in questions related to the issues on [skeptics.se] from very new members who've not taken the tour or figured out how to post well. On the 8 other sites I frequent, nothing much.

Comment: I do see more people including "... stands with Ukraine", etc. In their profile names.

Comment: I've had to yeet Chinese propaganda spammers with a fair amount of regularity. We've not had any *inorganic* responses to the issue so far, even where people are uncivil, its folks who would be using the network otherwise.